# How to send files from JavaScript together with form submission?

Tags: javascript, html

On my form, there is a button to select an image file. After pressing select You will be able to select additional image files. which every time a new image file is selected The input variable will also have a new value based on the last selected image. This causes me to store all image files with the variable in JS(imageMap). But when submitting the form, I can't send these image files from the variable in JS(imageMap).

```
<form id="my_form" name="my_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="....">
....
    <label for="img_picker">เลือกไฟล์ภาพ</label>
    <input type="file" id="img_picker" class="hidden" multiple>
    <div id="img_preview"></div>

<script>
    var imageMap = {};

    $('#img_picker').on('change', function () {
        for (const file of this.files) {
            const key = "id" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);
            imageMap[key] = file;

            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                const img = document.createElement('img');
                img.classList.add('img-thumbnail', 'mb-2');
                img.style.width = '100px';
                img.src = e.target.result;

                const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
                deleteButton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-danger', 'btn-sm');
                deleteButton.textContent = 'delete';
                deleteButton.onclick = () => {
                    img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
                    deleteButton.parentNode.removeChild(deleteButton);
                    delete imageMap[key];
                };

                const div = document.createElement('div');
                div.appendChild(img);
                div.appendChild(deleteButton);

                $('#img_preview').append(div);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }

        this.value = null;
    });
</script>

....
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary sub_form">save</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', ".sub_form", function () {
        document.getElementById('my_form').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Once, I tried to create the input to store these images and I used `$(#input_files).val(imageMap)` But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any solutions after I tried for 8 hours but I found it after I asked in the stackoverflow for 10 minutes. This is quite strange.

**Just use the `DataTransfer`.**

First, add a name for file input.

```
<input type="file" id="img_picker" class="hidden" name="imagePicker[]" multiple>
```

After this, transfer files with the DataTransfer before submitting this form.

```
<script>
    function getImageFromJS() {
        let data = new DataTransfer();
        for (const file of Object.values(imageMap)) {
        data.items.add(file);
        }
        document.getElementById('imagePicker').files = data.files;
    }

    $(document).on('click', ".sub_form", function () {
        getImageFromJS();
        document.getElementById('my_form').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Clever idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78053185/322084) using the DataTransfer object. Apparently that is the only kind of object that implements the FileList interface and at the same time has methods for adding elements/files.

An alternative approach could be to use the FormData object and then send the data using AJAX aka. using the fetch method (and then clear the form/list of images when the request is successful).

```js
var imageMap = {};

document.forms.my_form.images.addEventListener('change', e => {
  for (const file of e.target.files) {
    const key = "id" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);
    imageMap[key] = file;

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', e => {
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      img.classList.add('img-thumbnail', 'mb-2');
      img.style.width = '100px';
      img.src = e.target.result;

      const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
      deleteButton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-danger', 'btn-sm');
      deleteButton.textContent = 'delete';
      deleteButton.type = 'button';
      deleteButton.name = 'delete';
      deleteButton.dataset.key = key;
      
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.dataset.key = key;
      div.appendChild(img);
      div.appendChild(deleteButton);

      document.getElementById('img_preview').append(div);
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
  e.target.value = null;
});

document.forms.my_form.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  switch (e.target.name) {
    case 'delete':
      form.querySelector(`div[data-key="${e.target.dataset.key}"]`).remove();
      delete imageMap[e.target.dataset.key];
      break;
  }
});

document.forms.my_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  let data = new FormData(form);
  data.delete('images');
  for (const key of Object.keys(imageMap)) {
    data.append('images', imageMap[key]);
  }
  fetch(form.action, {method: form.method, body: data});
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="my_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="posturl">
  <label>
    <span>Select image file</span>
    <input type="file" name="images" class="hidden" multiple>
  </label>
  <div id="img_preview"></div>
  <button>Send</button>
</form>
```